# watch for programms using audio output in linux

Tags: linux, audio, watch

I would like to watch for programms outputing audio. Basically I try to make a system where I have VLC running in the background and if I start a video in firefox, VLC would automatically mute. Anyone have any idea how to do it ? A command line equivalent of `pavucontrol` would be cool I guess.

But a script or binary that would do something when there are more than one process that outputs audio would be really cool.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/47146/how-can-i-find-out-what-programs-are-using-sound-in-linux

Comment: Hi [mjgpy3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1378292/mjgpy3) and thanks for your repöy but I saw this topic before asking and it does not help me further. The best answer is `pavucontrol` but it only presents a GUI solution and I need a command line one.

Answer (score 1):

The `NewPlaybackStream` signal of the [PulseAudio D-Bus interface](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/Clients/DBus) will let you know when another application has begun playback (or technically when they've attached to the PulseAudio server, usually to play audio), and the opposite with `PlaybackStreamRemoved`.